# Youtube web scraping

Tags: python-3.x

I am scraping the title of some videos information on Youtube, But I get the 'empty list' result after running the following code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

pageContent=requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqV4mxzqIbA')
tree = html.fromstring(pageContent.text)
title = tree.xpath('//h1[@class="title style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer"]/text()')
```

I don't know why this happens, is the usage wrong? 
I am using python3.6

Answer (score 1):

It seems your XPath query is wrong. Try this instead:

```
title = tree.xpath("//span[@id='eow-title']/@title")
```

Comment: Can you please explain it concisely. For example, what should I do if I want to scrape 'viewers', 'post date', 'videoID'?

Comment: why i cannot find the same xpath using“inspect” of chrome or “firebug” of firefox